# Write a function accordian(l) that takes as input a list of integer returns True if the absolute difference of each adjacent element in increasing

Tags: list

Write a python function accordian(l) that takes as input a list of integer l and returns True if the absolute difference between each adjacent pair of elements alternates between increasing strictly and decreasing strictly

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

## Code witten by Debkanta Mondal #Python3

```
def accordian(l):
di=[]
res=[]
for x,y in zip(l[:],l[1:]):
    d1=abs(y-x)
    di.append(d1)
#print(di)
for i,j in zip(di[:],di[1:]):
    if i<j:
        flag=1
    elif i==j:
        flag=2
    else:
        flag=0
    res.append(flag)
#print(flag)
for s in res:
    if s==2:
        return False
        break

return all(m!=n for m,n in zip(res,res[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def expanding(l):
    c1=abs(l[1]-l[0]) # Difference of 1st 2 integers.
    for j in range(2,len(l)): 
        c2=abs(l[j]-l[j-1]) # Next difference = l[2]-l[1] 
        if c2 <= c1: # if next diff smaller/equal to prev diff 
            return(False) #return false
        else: # if next diff > prev diff
              c1=c2 # next diff be prev diff for next iteration.
    return(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def accordian(l):
    """
    Function : takes as input a list of integer l and returns True 
    if the absolute difference between each adjacent pair of elements 
    alternates between increasing strictly and decreasing strictly.
    Input : List
    Return : Boolean
    """
    size = len(l)
    diff = []

    if size < 3:
        return False

    for i in range(size-1):
        abs_diff = abs(l[i+1]-l[i])
        diff.append(abs_diff)

    if len(diff) == 2:
        if abs(diff[0] - diff[1]) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    result = [a < b for a, b in zip(diff, diff[1:])]
    for i in range(len(result)-1):
        if result[i] == result[i+1]:
            return False
    return True
```